# ASP.NET Webforms C# about check uniqueness on client side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I have a Registration form that has a text field for the user to type in their username. The user clicks on the submit button every time so that a check is made in the database for the username and if it exist then an error is displayed.

How to avoid using server side and instead use **Client side** to do the same process.

So far, I have the code in the server side which is:

```
                 protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

                  // Creating Connection.
                    SqlConnection con5 = new SqlConnection(_conString);
                    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(_conString);

                    // Creating Command.
                    SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand();
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

                    cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd5.Connection = con5;
                    cmd2.Connection = con2;

                    //creating a parameterized query for the Username and nic
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text.Trim());
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@national", txtnic.Text.Trim());

                    //search for username from tbl_organizer and tbl donor
                    cmd5.CommandText = "SELECT tbl_donor.don_uname  FROM tbl_organizer,tbl_donor,tbl_admin WHERE (tbl_donor.don_uname =@uname) or tbl_organizer.org_uname =@uname or tbl_admin.adm_uname =@uname";
                    cmd2.CommandText = "select * from tbl_organizer where org_nic=@national";
                    //Creating DataReader to read from database.
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    SqlDataReader dr2;
                    con5.Open();
                    con2.Open();
                    dr = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
                    dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    //Checking if username already exists in the DB.
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        lblErrMsg.Text = "Username Already Exist, Please Choose Another";
                        lblErrMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblErrMsg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        txtuname.Focus();
                    }
                    else{
                        // we continue to insert.
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this *client* side? You'd be sending the entire usernames to the client, exposing unnecessary confidential info. Even if you hash them it's trivial to build the rainbow table.

Comment: @Martheen, humm. I didnt know that. So, how can I make someone understand that it has to be server side rather than client side?

Comment: As @dhanusshetty pointed out in their answer, while you can make the process more seamless, ultimately you're saving a few seconds of user time in exchange for exposing them to security risk for the account's entire lifetime. Ask the stakeholder to consider if they'd like advertisers to know every account they have in various sites.

Comment: @dhanush shetty and @ Martheen thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Having usernames on the client side is not a feasible solution, plus its a security vulnerability. You're essentially leaking data & can lead to enumeration attacks. You can probably add a server event on text-change like this which would be called on tab-out(blur). This can do a check to see if username exists or not.

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtuname" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtuname_TextChanged" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void txtuname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text.Trim());
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tbl_donor.don_uname  FROM tbl_organizer,tbl_donor,tbl_admin WHERE (tbl_donor.don_uname =@uname) or tbl_organizer.org_uname =@uname or tbl_admin.adm_uname =@uname";

   SqlDataReader dr;
   con.Open();
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
       lblErrMsg.Text = "Username Already Exist, Please Choose Another";
       lblErrMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       lblErrMsg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
       txtuname.Focus();
   }
}
```

We even removed this feature from our website at work because of possible enumeration attacks although its a negative on the usability pov. So think & implement the same.